# Authenticate user from server phonegap

Tags: jquery, database, cordova

I want to authenticate user from server but when I send a request to the server, I get an error. Also, on the server, I have columns "phone" and "name" from where I want to authenticate a user. Please tell me what I am doing wrong

```
 $(".signupbtn").click(function()
{

var Mobile=$("#Mobile").val();
var key=$("#key").val();
var dataString="phone="+Mobile+"name="+key;

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url.php",
        data: dataString,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,


        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data=="success")
            {

                window.location.assign = "index.html";
            }
            else(err)
            {
                alert("error"+err);
                $(".signupbtn").html('error');
            }
        }
    });
   return false;
 });
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? Please take a look at our [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and creating a [minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: not able to make connection to the remote server

Comment: are you testing it in a browser ?

Comment: no, i am using emulator..